# Where can I check tornado's log file?

Tags: python, tornado

I think there was a default log file, but I didn't find it yet.

Sometimes the HTTP request process would throw an exception on the screen, but I suggest it also goes somewhere on the disk or I wouldn't know what was wrong during a long run test.

P.S.: write an exception handler is another topic; first I'd like to know my question's answer.

I found something here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/python-tornado/px4R8Tkfa9c

But it also didn't mention where can I find those log.

Comment: if you are in linux, why not sending the console to a file ( using the > or >> )

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It uses standard python logging module by default.

Here is [definition](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/tornado/log.py#L47):

```
access_log = logging.getLogger("tornado.access")
app_log = logging.getLogger("tornado.application")
gen_log = logging.getLogger("tornado.general")
```

It doesn't write to files by default. You can run it using [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) and define in supervisord config, where log files will be located. It will capture output of tornado and write it to files.

Also you can think [this way](http://www.joet3ch.com/blog/2011/09/08/alternative-tornado-logging/):

```
tornado.options.options['log_file_prefix'].set('/opt/logs/my_app.log')
tornado.options.parse_command_line()
```

But in this case - measure performance. I don't suggest you to write to files directly from tornado application, if it can be delegated.

FYI: [`parse_command_line`](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/tornado/options.py#L109) just enables [pretty console logging](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/tornado/options.py#L138).

Comment: @ColeMaclean thought you are not around :)

Comment: @NikolayFominyh Thanks for your inputs. When you say delegating the log to supervisord helps against reduced performance by doing it in tornado, are you saying supervisord is buffering it before flushing to appropriate file(s)? Can you elaborate a bit more on the performance reasons?

Comment: +1 not only a quick solution, but also info on how to do it better!

@Ethan: supervisord uses subprocesses, instead of otherwise blocking the main thread (while writing log entries to disk).

Answer (score 3):

With newer versions, you may do

```
args = sys.argv
args.append("--log_file_prefix=/opt/logs/my_app.log")
tornado.options.parse_command_line(args)
```

or as @ColeMaclean mentioned, providing

```
--log_file_prefix=PATH
```

at command line

Answer (score 1):

There's no logfile by default.

You can use the `--log_file_prefix=PATH` command line option to set one.

Tornado just uses the [Python stdlib's logging module](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html), if you're trying to do anything more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Use `RotatingFileHandler`:

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler

log_path = "/path/to/tornado.access.log"
logger_ = logging.getLogger("tornado.access")
logger_.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger_.propagate = False
handler = RotatingFileHandler(log_path, maxBytes=1024*1024*1024, backupCount=3)
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("[%(name)s][%(asctime)s][%(levelname)s][%(pathname)s:%(lineno)d] > %(message)s"))
logger_.addHandler(handler)
```