# How do I use logging in python tornado and write to file

Tags: python, tornado

Currently I'm using `logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)` what I think is logging everything where logging level is => DEBUG Is that a correct assumption? I can see a difference when I set logging.DEBUG to logging.ERROR so I guess I'm correct.

Also how do I write these logging rows to a file?

Comment: How are you starting the application?

Answer (score -2):

This is a exmaple write log to file

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# create a file handler

handler = logging.FileHandler('hello.log')
handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# create a logging format

formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)

# add the handlers to the logger

logger.addHandler(handler)

logger.info('Hello baby')
```

More detail:
http://victorlin.me/posts/2012/08/good-logging-practice-in-python/

Comment: The code and article you suggested seems to only log rows where you explicit says it to log. What I'm searching for is a way to fetch the tornado's own logging that it prints to the console window to a file.

Comment: @PresidentCamacho If that is your question, then it is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12593460/where-can-i-check-tornados-log-file. Consider editing your main question.